# rd-acl says I can make a project, but the Rundeck UI says I can't. What is wrong here?

Tags: rundeck

I put an acl policy in /etc/rundeck for my group.

```
rd-acl test -c application -g "Cloud Team" -a create -G project
Using configured Rundeck etc dir: /etc/rundeck
The decision was: allowed
The test passed
```

Then I log into Rundeck via the website and I see this:

```
You have no authorized access to projects.
Contact your administrator. (User roles: ..., Cloud Team, ...)
```

For good measure, I temporarily made another acl policy for my user.
I pass the test with my user name.
rd-acl test -c application -u myuser -a create -G project

I also tried a group that does not have a space in the name and got the same results.

If it makes a difference, I am logging in using my AD credentials and the groups are being pulled in from AD.

This is in Rundeck 3.0.20-20190408

My acl policy

```
description: Admin, all access.
context:
  project: '.*' # all projects
for:
  resource:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/create all kinds
  adhoc:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/running/killing adhoc jobs
  job:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/write/delete/run/kill of all jobs
  node:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/run for all nodes
by:
  group: Cloud Team

---

description: Admin, all access.
context:
  application: 'rundeck'
for:
  resource:
    - allow: '*' # allow create of projects
  project:
    - allow: '*' # allow view/admin of all projects
  project_acl:
    - allow: '*' # allow admin of all project-level ACL policies
  storage:
    - allow: '*' # allow read/create/update/delete for all /keys/* storage content
by:
  group: Cloud Team
```

I see errors like this in rundeck.access.log

```
Evaluating Decision for: res<type:resource, kind:project> subject<Username:MyNameHere Group:OneOfMyGroups Group:AnotherGroup Group:Cloud Team> action<create> env<rundeck:auth:env:application:run
deck>: authorized: false:       No context matches subject or environment => REJECTED_NO_SUBJECT_OR_ENV_FOUND (0ms)
```

Comment: Maybe you have another ACL that overrides this?

Comment: I removed all the other policies to be sure and it didn't work.  However, I did get this working in the end.

At first, I just copied the admin aclpolicy and changed the group over to Cloud Team.  That doesn't seem to work.  so I ran rd-acl create ... >> cloudteam.aclpolicy over and over, granting access to everything individually.  Now it works.